# Read a PDF file and return as stream from a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, stream

I want to create a WCF service (working like windows service). This service will read a PDF file from a specific path, extract pages, create a new PDF file and return it to the caller.

How can I do this ? I use QuickPDF to process on PDF files, I can extract and create new PDF file. How can use this in a WCF service ?

Waiting your helps...

This is only sample code :

```
public Stream ExtractPdf(string PathOfOriginalPdfFile, int StartPage,int PageCount)
{
        PDFLibrary qp = new PDFLibrary();
        Stream Stream_ = null;

        if (qp.UnlockKey(".................") == 0)
        {
            string fileName = @"..\..\Test Files\sample1.pdf";
            string OutputFile = @"..\..\Test Files\sample1_extracted.pdf";

            if (qp.Unlocked() == 1)
            {

                int docID = qp.LoadFromFile(fileName, "");

                int extractPageSuccess = qp.ExtractPages(StartPage, PageCount);

                if (extractPageSuccess == 0)
                {
                    // error
                }
                else
                {
                    qp.SaveToFile(OutputFile);
                }
            }
        }

        //
        // Codes here
        //
        return Stream_;
    }
```

I edited it :

```
 public byte[] ExtractPdf(string PathOfOriginalPdfFile, int StartPage,int PageCount)
    {

        QuickPDFDLL0815.PDFLibrary qp = new QuickPDFDLL0815.PDFLibrary(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Quick PDF Library\DLL\QuickPDFDLL0815.dll");

        string fileName = @"..\..\Test Files\sample1.pdf";
        byte[] binFile = null;

        if (qp.UnlockKey("...................") == 0)
        {


            if (qp.Unlocked() == 1)
            {

                int docID = qp.LoadFromFile(fileName, "");

                int extractPageSuccess = qp.ExtractPages(StartPage, PageCount);

                if (extractPageSuccess == 0)
                {
                    // error
                }
                else
                {
                   binFile = qp.SaveToString();
                }
            }
        }

        return binFile;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could send the file as a `Stream`, see [How to: Enable Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx), then on the client save off the file and have the shell execute it. The MSDN article includes a sample `GetStream` method as well as a whole section on `Writing a custom stream`.

If you would like *fuller* sample code the forum post [Streamed file transfer using WCF](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/forums/streamed-file-transfer-using-wcf/p/2736/29545.aspx)  starts with some, however, note that the author posted it there because they were encountering issues running it.

As to byte[] or stream see [Uploading Image Blobs–Stream vs Byte Array](http://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/uploading-image-blobsstream-vs-byte-array-year-of-azure-week-4/) and [Stream vs Raw Bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295478/stream-vs-raw-bytes). The second states

> Streams will perform better for large files since not all of it needs to be read into memory at one time

Comment: i added a new code sample.Which best way to return pdf file ? Stream or byte[] and why ?