# Return pdf file from WCF service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service and I want to one of its service methods to access a pdf file and convert it to a stream or some other thing and return the stream to my web application, where I will be converting that stream back to a pdf file.

Which is the better way, converting the pdf into `Stream` or `byte[]` array?

This is my method

```
 public byte[] GetPdf(string Address)
 {
    byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Address);
    return bytes
 }
```

Now in my web application from which I am calling this WCF service, I want to use these bytes and convert them back to pdf. Is this the correct way as I'm not sure whether returning the file as stream is correct or returning as `byte[]` is correct

But when I'm running the service for testing purpose I'm getting an error

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

How can I resolve this issue, I have not added any bindings or anything, everything is default as I'm new to WCF

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF - How to Increase Message Size Quota](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota)

Comment: I don't see this is a duplicate of the message size quota question... the answer to this can and should be different.  It is similar to another question though...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read a PDF file and return as stream from a WCF service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448694/read-a-pdf-file-and-return-as-stream-from-a-wcf-service)

Answer (score 2):

Good Day!

Quote from the book "[Programming WCF Services](http://books.google.ru/books?id=PvNrurEhmiEC&pg=PA617&dq=wcf&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=ljVoUs2kEYb-4QTBoIGgBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=wcf&f=false)" author Juval Lowy:

> By default, when  the  client  and  the  service  exchange messages, 
>   these messages  are buffered on  the  receiving  end and delivered
>   only once  the  entire message has been received. This  is true
>   whether  it  is the client sending a message to the service or the
>   service returning a message to the client. As a result, when the
>   client calls the service, the service is invoked only after the
>   client’s message has been received in its entirety; likewise, the
>   client is unblocked only once the returned message with the results of
>   the invocation has been received in its entirety. For sufficiently
>   small messages, this exchange pattern provides for a simple program-
>   ming model because the latency caused by receiving the message is
>   usually negligible compared with the message processing itself.
>   However, when it comes to much larger messages—such as ones involving
>   multimedia content, large files, or batches of data— blocking until
>   the entire message has been received may be impractical. To handle
>   such cases, WCF enables the receiving side (be it the client or the
>   service) to start processing the data in the message while the message
>   is still being received by the channel. This type of processing is
>   known as streaming transfer mode. With large payloads, streaming
>   provides improved throughput and responsiveness because neither the
>   receiving nor the sending side is blocked while the message is being
>   sent or received

For transfer files, I'm recomended using Stream with async pattern.

```
 [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
    public interface ITerrasoftFiles
    {
        [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
        IAsyncResult BeginGetFiles(Guid ID, AsyncCallback asyncCallBack, object asyncState);

        Stream EndGetFiles(IAsyncResult res);

        [OperationContract]
        FileInfo GetFileInfo(Guid ID);
    }
```

And set **transferMode="StreamedResponse"** in Web.config

```
<bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="tcpTerrasoftFiles" transferMode="StreamedResponse">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
 <services>
    <service name="TWebServices.Services.TerrasoftFiles">
      <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="tcpTerrasoftFiles" 
                  contract="TWebServices.Services.ITerrasoftFiles" />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
     </service>
 </services>
```