# Send images through named pipe

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, bitmap, named-pipes

I have used this [WCF tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication) to create a named pipe and it works well for me. However, i want to send an image (.bmp, .jpg etc. or any other standard format) from the the server to the client. The [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) does not work and it gives me an error.

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

I tried changing the app.config file with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476853/wcf-error-maximum-number-of-items-that-can-be-serialized-or-deserialized-in-an/8656402#8656402). How else can I send it?

Answer (score 0):

Good Day!

For transfer any file, it is better to use Stream trasmission. I'm recomended read book "[Programming WCF Services"](http://books.google.ru/books?id=PvNrurEhmiEC&pg=PA617&dq=wcf&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=ljVoUs2kEYb-4QTBoIGgBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=wcf&f=false) 3 edition author Juval Lowy (p.251).

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITerrasoftFiles
{
    [OperationContract]
    Stream GetFiles(Guid ID);
}
```

You can also see the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549423/return-pdf-file-from-wcf-service/19551656#19551656) where a similar question was asked